# JPA ignores a field when persisting an entity

Tags: java, jpa, entity

I have problem in a JPA entity class. This entity was working perfectly as it should but today
i added another field (a simple string, varchar(255) NOT NULL in the database). When I try to persist a new entity i get an

```
java.sql.SQLException: Field 'companyLogoUrl' doesn't have a default value
```

Well, this is true. The column does not have a default value. but in my code i set the value for it. When I have a look at the generated insert statement the field is not present.

```
INSERT INTO COMPANY (ACCOUNTNUMBER, ACCOUNTOWNER, BANK, BANKCODE, CHANGEDAT, 
COMPANYNAME, CREATEDAT, addressId)
```

The name of the variable matches the the column-name so there are no annotations which could cause the error. It is treated just like the other fields/columns which work fine.

Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT:

Here is the class (a groovy-class):

```
@Entity
class Company extends KupiumEntity
{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
final int companyId

String companyName
String bank
String bankCode
String accountNumber
String accountOwner

String companyLogoUrl


@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name="addressId")
Address address = new Address()


@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="companyId")
List<Invoice> invoices = new ArrayList<Invoice>()


@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="companyId")
List<Kupon> kupons = new ArrayList<Kupon>()


@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="mandatorId")
List<Mandator> mandators = new ArrayList<Mandator>()


@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="companyAppId")
List<CompanyApp> companyApps = new ArrayList<CompanyApp>()
}
```

EDIT 2:
Sorry for the confusion. The field and the column in the table are named 'companyLogoUrl'

Comment: Please post your entity class.

Comment: We need to see your Java code/mapping. There must be *some* difference between existing and new field, like missing annotation, getter/setter, incorrect modifier...

Comment: It doesn't look like this class quite matches up with your generated SQL... CHANGEDAT? CREATEDAT? Are you sure everything is on the same page here?

Comment: I don't see logoUrl field. You are using field access, so the field name matters, not getter/setter (if you have one)

Comment: Hmmm, mystery edit shows your database field as matching your entity now. I would have sworn that was not the case when I posted my answer.

Comment: @Beau Grantham: ChangedAt and CreatedAt are inherited from a MappedSuperclass. This class only contains these two values (and works fine ;))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I solved this issue today, though i am still not aware what the cause is.

I tried to run my unitTests and these told me that they could not find the pom.xml in this project. This was somehow surprising since it is no Maven-Project so I do not understand why he was even looking for it. Anyway, I created a new Project, copied the source from the old to the new one and... it works.

I still find it hard to figure out why eclipse would even think about it as a maven project (why else would he look for a pom.xml?)

And again I apologize for the confusion about the names of fields/columns. Thanks for your help, guys!